# SQL to link three tables and SUM

Tags: php, sql

I have three tables, tblPresents, tblPresentsOrdered and tblPresentsDelivered.

What I want to do is sum up all the orders and deliveries for a given present ID, so I can tally up the total ordered and delivered and check for discrepancies.

So far I have the following:

```
$sql ='SELECT prsName, SUM(ordQuantity) AS qtyOrdered,
SUM(delQuantity) AS qtyDelivered
FROM tblPresentOrders
LEFT JOIN tblPresentDeliveries
ON tblPresentDeliveries.delPresent = tblPresentOrders.ordPresent
RIGHT JOIN tblPresents ON tblPresents.prsID = tblPresentOrders.ordPresent
GROUP BY prsName';
```

The first column (Ordered) is summing up correctly, but the deliveries is counting the delivery twice (there are two separate orders for that line).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My guess without looking at the data is that there are multiple `delPresent` for each `ordPresent`. Is it a one-to-one?

Comment: It is a one-to-many, one present might have multiple orders and deliveries, but at the moment there are two records in the 'Orders' table and only one in the 'Deliveries' table.

Comment: Is there one order per delivery and vice-versa?

Comment: Not necessarily. Sometimes we have top-up orders or deliveries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can have multiple orders per delivery (and presumably multiple presents per order) you need to perform aggregation in derived tables before `JOIN`ing to avoid duplication in counted/summed values. Note that using a mixture of `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` in the same query can be a bit hard to read so I've rewritten the query using only `LEFT JOIN`s.

```
SELECT p.prsName, o.qtyOrdered, d.qtyDelivered
FROM tblPresents p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ordPresent, SUM(ordQuantity) AS qtyOrdered
           FROM tblPresentOrders
           GROUP BY ordPresent) o ON o.ordPresent = p.prsID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT delPresent, SUM(delQuantity) AS qtyDelivered
           FROM tblPresentDeliveries
           GROUP BY delPresent) d ON d.delPresent = p.prsID
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly and I think I understand why. Just one question though, what's the purpose of tblPresents p? Is is just a shorthand, or does it actually mean something? When I tried it without that, it threw up an SQL error.

Comment: @ChrisC `tblPresents p` (can also be written as `tblPresents AS p`) sets `p` as an alias for `tblPresents` which just makes writing the rest of the query shorter. It's completely optional, I find it helps readability.